# jquery: set cookie and use a jquery-function at once

Tags: jquery, cookies

to show a div onLoad and hide it onClick I use this

```
<div id="cookiebanner">blah blah blah
    <button type="button" class="cookiebanner">close</button>
</div>
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#cookiebanner' ).show( 'slow' );
    $( 'button.cookiebanner' ).click(function() {
       $( '#cookiebanner' ).hide( 'slow' );
    });
});
```

This works fine.
How can a cookie be inserted to prevend displaying after clicking on 'close'?
If I insert a $.cookie() it doesn't run anymore. Where´s my error?

```
$( 'button.cookiebanner' ).click(function() {
    $.cookie('COOKIEBANNER', 'have_seen_it');
    $( '#cookiebanner' ).hide( 'slow' );
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check your console?

Comment: yes, there are also by php (my php-code) written cookies, and thats all ok

Comment: Writing cookies with php and writing them with javascript are completely different. I would guess that your javascript console has something like `undefined is not a function`. Are you sure you included the jquery.cookie library correctly?

Comment: OMG! forgot the '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>'
sorry and thanks!
can be downloaded at http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/